# nodejs socket behaves quirkily when passing buffer passed to write

Tags: node.js, sockets, buffer

I'm setting up a simple test for binary data being sent on a socket.

On the transmit side I simply encode the number of arguments passed to the invocation, and then for each argument I encode the length of that argument.  This gives me a quick and easy way to test sending varying binary data:

```
var client = new net.Socket()
client.connect(9999, host, function() {
    console.log("Connected")
    // convert argument list into length delimited parameters
    var i,args = process.argv.length-3
    var buf = new Buffer(4)
    buf.writeInt32LE(args,0)
    client.write(buf)
    console.log("sending "+args+" args")
    for (i=3;i<args+3;i++) {
        console.log("["+(i-3)+"] "+process.argv[i].length)
        buf.writeInt32LE(process.argv[i].length)
        client.write(buf)
    }
    client.end()    
})
```

On the receive side I extra the number of arguments, then for each argument I extract the length of that argument, and print the whole thing. I use a little state machine to keep track of where I am in the reading.

```
var server = net.createServer(function(x) {
    console.log("connected")
    var state=0,args,argn
    x.on("readable",function() {
        switch (state) {
        case 0:
            var n = x.read(4)
            console.log("[0]"); console.dir(n)
            if (n === null) return
            args=n.readInt32LE(0)
            console.log(args+" arguments")
            state = 1 ; argn = 0
            break
        case 1:
            var n = x.read(4)
            console.log("[1]"); console.dir(n)
            if (n === null) return
            console.log("argument "+argn+" has "+n.readInt32LE(0)+" bytes")
            if (++argn > args) {
                console.log("end of arguments")
                state = 0
            }
            break
        default:
            console.log("state="+state+", now what?")
    }
})
x.on("close",function() { console.log("closed") })
x.on("end",function() { console.log("ended") })

server.listen({port:9999})
```

The issue that I am seeing is that I never seem to receive the last two argument lengths (32-bit integers).  I have tried sending one or two additional integers on the transmit side just to see if it makes a difference and it does not.  I simply never see the *readable* callback ever called as many times as it is supposed to.

For instance, if on the client side I invoke with:

```
node tcptest.js tx "Hello world" 12345 AAA 9
```

The output on the client side is:

```
sending
Connected
sending 4 args
[0] 10
[1] 5
[2] 3
[3] 1
Connection closed
```

But on the server side, all I see is:

```
receiving
connected
[0]
Buffer [ 4, 0, 0, 0 ]
4 arguments
[1]
Buffer [ 10, 0, 0, 0 ]
argument 0 has 10 bytes
[1]
Buffer [ 5, 0, 0, 0 ]
argument 1 has 5 bytes
socket ended
socket closed
```

I tried not re-using the `buf` object and it worked for a while, but then began intermittently failing again.

```
...
for (i=3;i<args+3;i++) {
    buf = new Buffer(4)
    console.log("["+(i-3)+"] "+process.argv[i].length)
...
```

When it started working again for a while I thought maybe there was something undocumented which disallowed a Buffer from being reused for passing to write, but now I don't know.  If I don't use Buffer at all, e.g. if I pipe stdin to the socket, then it works fine, but if I try to construct binary data like this is doesn't always get received.

What could I be doing wrong?

Update:
If I call `read()` on the server side instead of specifying a number of bytes, then I see all the data received!  I suspect what is happening is that if I read less than the number of bytes available, I don't get an additional callback.

Comment: Have you tried just doing something like `socket.pipe(decrypter).pipe(process.stdout)` on the server?

Comment: @idbehold yeah, something similar to that works (except on the client). I have rewritten the question... it appears to have nothing to do with encryption at all and everything to do with re-using the Buffer object

Answer (score 0):

The "readable" event is only firing once for each additional piece of data which is received.  The above code assumes that it will be fired again upon return if all the available data is not read, but this is not true.

The following code fixes the problem by wrapping the state machine in a loop that continues to pull data until it can't get the next expected chunk:

```
x.on("readable",function() {
    while (true) {
        switch (state) {
        case 0:
            var n = x.read(4)
            console.log("[0]"); console.dir(n)
            if (n === null) return
            args=n.readInt32LE(0)
            console.log(args+" arguments")
            state = 1 ; argn = 0
            break
        case 1:
            var n = x.read(4)
            console.log("[1]"); console.dir(n)
            if (n === null) return
            console.log("argument "+argn+" has "+n.readInt32LE(0)+" bytes")
            if (++argn > args) {
                console.log("end of arguments")
                state = 0
            }
            break
        default:
            console.log("state="+state+", now what?")
            return
    }
}
```